# How to initialise a vector of unknown dims, based on an existing one in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried the following were I just want the elements in the 3rd dimension of the `arr` array to be swapped:

```
function switch_coordinate_columns3D(arr) {
    var result = arr;
    console.log(arr.length) // 1
    console.log(arr[0].length) // 145
    console.log(arr[0][0].length) // 2
    console.log("Before:")
    console.log(arr[0][0][0]) // 2.34399445270253
    console.log(arr[0][0][1]) // 48.81610278648994
    console.log(result[0][0][0]) // 2.34399445270253
    console.log(result[0][0][1])  // 48.81610278648994
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            result[i][j][0] = arr[i][j][1];
            result[i][j][1] = arr[i][j][0];
        }
        console.log("After:")
        console.log(arr[0][0][0])  // 48.81610278648994
        console.log(result[0][0][0])  // 48.81610278648994
        console.log(arr[0][0][1]) // 48.81610278648994
        console.log(result[0][0][1]) // 48.81610278648994
    }
    return result
}
```

I used the `var result = arr` step to initialise dimensions as `arr` can be complex with different lengths of `arr[i]`'s over `i`.

However, my understanding is that this fails because in the first step `arr` is passed by reference and not by value to `result`?

Am I correct? And how should I do instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `var result = arr;` simply assigns a reference, so mutations to one are seen in the other and your swaps don't work as expected. If you want to work on a clone, for a nested array, use [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments by @pilchard, I could solve my issue with:

```
function switch_coordinate_columns3D(arr) {
    var result = []
    result = structuredClone(arr);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            result[i][j][0] = arr[i][j][1];
            result[i][j][1] = arr[i][j][0];
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Side note:
I would be interested if somebody could explain me why using directly `var result = structuredClone(arr);` was not working, in the sense of still assigning the reference rather than the value.